# Media on PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, cordova

I want to change the color of a label when the user hits a button, and play a happy sound, like this:

```
$("#label").css("color","green");
new Media("/audio/happy.mp3").play();
```

But the result is: the sound reproduces, and after that, the label changes to green.

Is there any way to make the label to get green before (or during) the sound reproduction?

Thanks!

Comment: try `document.getElementById('label').style.color = 'green';` instead... since it's all javascript it should be a bit faster... not too hopeful that it will work.. but worth a shot

Comment: thanks Cory, I also tried that, but does not work :(

Comment: SOLUTION: Instead of doing both things in the same event, I do the color change on a "touchstart" event, and the play in a "touched" event!

Comment: You should post that as a solution to this question, and then mark it so that people who come across this while googling for help might find it easier.

Comment: done, but I can't mark my own answer as the correct one :)

Comment: You have to wait about 24 hours before you can mark your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION: Instead of doing both things in the same event, I do the color change on a "touchstart" event, and the play in a "touched" event!